# VBA Finding cell value in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing an algorithm and wanted to do a try-out in Excel VBA. After some criteria is met, I want to find a cell value in a certain range (and it is definitively there) but VBA doesn't seem to find it.

I have looked for similar cases and also have tried diming variables and adding them to my code, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to use debug.print for the Range("AA2:AA16"), it runs into a error.
It works for the other range.

```
Sheets(9).Range("AA2:AA16").Find (Sheets(9).Range("AK2").Value)     
Debug.Print Sheets(9).Range("AA2:AA16").Find(Sheets(9).Range("AK2").Value).Adress

Sheets(9).Range("AA1:AD1").Find (Sheets(9).Range("AM3").Value)
Debug.Print Sheets(9).Range("AA1:AD1").Find(Sheets(9).Range("AM3").Value).Address
```

I expect it to find the AK2 value in the "AA2:AA16" range and return the address. After that I want the code to select the line of that find, to select the column of the AM3 value in range "AA1:AD1" and then intersect both and sum 1 to that intersection.

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: There's a typo in `Address` on the first example.

Comment: @Luuklag

[link]https://paste.pics/484aaf29a54174c7620be2ad2cd78d24

Based on the image, what I want to do is: 
I want to grab the value from the cell in G2 and find its position in the Range "A3:A11". Once that hapens I want the row number. 

Next I want to grab the value from the cell G3 and find its position in the Range "B2:B4". Once that happens I want the column number.

I then want to intersect the row and column and add 1 to that intersection.

Comment: @gbavba

You're right, but I fixed it, and there was still an error

Comment: Would have been too easy... Not sure why it isn't working. I would start debugging by checking `Debug.Print Sheets(9).Range("AK2").Value = Sheets(9).Range("{cell that contains the search term}").Value` if that returns True it would rule out it being a problem with data types.

Comment: @gbavba

I tried your method and it returned true, it is equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your problem right. Try to understand this code, it should guide you.

[image: screenshot of example]

```
Sub test()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets(1).Range("A2:A8").Find(Sheets(1).Range("A13"))
    If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print r1.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If

    Set r2 = Sheets(1).Range("B1:D1").Find(Sheets(1).Range("A14"))
    If Not r2 Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print r2.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If

    If Not (r1 Is Nothing Or r2 Is Nothing) Then
        Set r3 = Cells(r1.Row, r2.Column)
        Debug.Print r3.Address
        Debug.Print r3.Value
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a valid declaration of your variables r1 and r2. They are now both declared as variant, and only r3 is declared as range. You should declare them one at a time: `Dim r1 as Range, r2 as Range, r3 as Range`

Comment: By applying and adjusting your code to mine, it still doesn't work for the r1 variable it always appear "not found".

Comment: @Morters  You could try to add `.value` behind the `Range("A13")`.

Comment: You might want to use `Trim()` around the `Range().Value` then to avoid any leading or trailing spaces

Comment: @Luuklag my bad, you're right of course concerning the declaration.

Comment: @Morters you have to analyse the values that are supposed to match. There must be a difference.

Comment: Hello guys, just an update:

I have solved the problem. It had to do with the fact that the value for the range "A2:A8" I was grabing it from other cells, I had that range equal to other range, and by posting the values it seems to have worked! Thank you all!!